# CORS, S3 and CloudFront configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Whenever I try to POST a file to my S3 bucket, I get the following error message:

```
POST https://api.*.com/sermon 413
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api*.com/sermon' from origin 'https://*.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My S3 ELB bucket is configured as follows (for `https://api.*.com/sermon`):

[image]

My Cloudfront is set up as follows (for `https://api.*.com/sermon`):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've also set up a CloudFront Origin Response trigger as a Lambda function:

```
'use strict';

// If the response lacks a Vary: header, fix it in a CloudFront Origin Response trigger.

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    if (!headers['vary'])
    {
        headers['vary'] = [
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' },
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Access-Control-Request-Method' },
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Origin' },
        ];
    }
    callback(null, response);
};
```

HTTP status:

[image]

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error instead of a 200 OK success response? And have you tried in a different browser? Or tried clearing your browser cache/ force-reloading?

Comment: I see you are using [my example Lambda code](https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161), so I should mention that this code is a solution for a different problem, a problem impacting only `GET` and `HEAD` requests.  The problem here is that you appear to be using S3 incorrectly and it's throwing an error that also happens not to have CORS headers... but the CORS error appears to be a distraction.  To send a `POST` upload to S3, the URI is always `/` -- the object key for the upload is provided in the form body.  You are posting to `/sermon` and it's unclear what you intend for that to do.

Comment: @sideshowbarker added HTTP status code to the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS setup is on S3, but looks like you're hitting an HTTP 413 ("Payload too Large") at CloudFront, prior to reaching S3.  So this issue is not really related to CORS per se.

HTTP 413 usually means exceeding the CloudFront request size of 20 kb, or the URL length of 8 kb.  Note the 'request size' is defined to include the request headers & query strings but not the request body.

So the first thing is to verify that the request size & URL length limits aren't being exceeded.  And that any payload is in the POST *body*, not part of a request header.

Also see if uploading smaller files (< 100 mb) will work, to rule out any issues around multipart uploads.

Comment: Peekay, 413 is from the backend as you can see Server: Ngnix but yeah normally 4xx response doesn't carry CORS header and lambda also won't add CORS header because you can't trigger lambda viewer request/response for 4xx.